# Webpack HotModuleReplacementPlugin not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I'm new to webpack and trying to explore on how to be able to use it in some of my projects. I have installed webpack-hot-middleware on my local project and below are my codes in webpack.config.js. 
After I run webpack command it doesnt do anything, doesnt open new browser tab and show the webpage, it doesnt display any error in terminal. What am I missing here?

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './dev/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            },
            { 
                test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { 
                from: './node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap', 
                to: 'assets/fonts/bootstrap' 
            }
        ]),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Terminal output:

```
Hash: e15c5a889e59610134b2
Version: webpack 3.4.1
Time: 3123ms
                                                    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                                                 index.js  1.79 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
                                             index.js.map  2.24 MB       0  [emitted]         main
  assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot  20.1 kB          [emitted]         
assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2    18 kB          [emitted]         
 assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff  23.4 kB          [emitted]         
  assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf  45.4 kB          [emitted]         
  assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg   109 kB          [emitted]         
   [2] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./dev/sass/style.scss 159 kB {0} [built]
   [5] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
   [6] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
 [127] ./dev/index.js 94 bytes {0} [built]
 [128] ./dev/sass/style.scss 1.15 kB {0} [built]
 [132] ./dev/bootstrap.js 214 bytes {0} [built]
 [136] ./node_modules/moment/locale ^\.\/.*$ 2.79 kB {0} [optional] [built]
 [157] ./dev/app.js 13 bytes {0} [built]
    + 150 hidden modules
```

Comment: You need to add more information. What command do you start your development environment with? What development server do you use? `webpack-dev-server`, `express`, `koa` etc.

Comment: Still same issue with me
also not solve with your rply ans :/